# Intersection between arc and rectangle

Tags: geometry, collision-detection, intersection

Say that there is an arc and a rectangle.

The arc has a position, radius, minimum and maximum angles, and the width of the arc itself. The rectangle has a position, width and height, and rotation.

How would one determine whether the arc and rectangle are intersecting?

[Provided is a visual aid that may increase clarity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9qDb.png) The green rectangles are those that would be considered to be intersecting, while the red rectangles are not intersecting.

I have determined that it is common to check intersections on each line segment of the rectangle individually, but I am not yet certain as to how one would account for the rectangle being on the inside of the arc but not close enough to be intersecting it.

Answer (score 0):

For rectangles being completely inside the arc you can check - whether any corner point `(x, y)` belongs to thick arc. For arc center `(cx, cy)`, inner and outer radii `r` and `R` and angles `a0,a1`:

```
dist = length(x - cx, y - cy)
if dist lies in range r..R:
   angle = atan2(y-cy, x-cx)
   if angle in range a0..a1:
       rectangle is inside
```

One more non-standard case: to find whether arc completely lies inside large rectangle - just check if any point of arc lies in that rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, it seems that this would not account for rectangles that intersect the arc without the center point or any of the corners being contained in the arc [like so.](https://i.imgur.com/pABVJ1T.png) This is why you would need to check the line segments rather than just the center point of the rectangle, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @PTOTAindustries You should check intersection of edges at first. If there is no intersection - check point in arc. It is usual practice in comp.geometry

Comment: OK, but how would you do so? I can only find methods of determining the boolean value of line-circle intersections, but without knowing where the intersection took place it isn't possible to know if it was in the arc or not.

Comment: Calculation of intersection should give angle of intersection point against arc center (like I used atan2)

Comment: Right. I'm just having trouble finding algorithms that return the angle of intersection and work for line segments rather than infinite lines. If you could find or come up with one, that would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: Define segment in parametric form P = P0 + t * (P1 - P0)  and substitute P.X and P.Y into circle equation. Solve quadratic equation for t. If roots are in range 0..1 -  intersection lies on segment, Then calculate angle.